# Recyclerview's Onscroll is not working while fetching data from firebase

Tags: java, android, xml, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I want to add onScroll Listener, but recyclerview's addonScrollListner() method is not doing anything, I want to fetch next ten items on every recyclerview's scroll.

At first time the data is fetching fine, but when i am scrolling recyclerview then nothing is happening, i am not able to find out why is this happening.

It is my code:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_content);
        MobileAds.initialize(this, new OnInitializationCompleteListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInitializationComplete(InitializationStatus initializationStatus) {
            }
        });
        mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView_con);
        progressBar = findViewById(R.id.contentprogressbar);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.listview);
        mSwipeRefreshLayout = findViewById(R.id.swipeContainer);
        textView = findViewById(R.id.emptylist);
        backbtncontent = findViewById(R.id.backbtncntent);
        backbtncontent.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(ContentActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        classname = getIntent().getStringExtra("classname");
        if (classname.equals("A")) {
            content = getIntent().getStringExtra("jokecontent");
        } else if (classname.equals("B")) {
            content = getIntent().getStringExtra("shayaricontent");
        }
        getLastKeyFromFirebase();
        final LinearLayoutManager layoutManager= new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        DividerItemDecoration dividerItemDecoration = new DividerItemDecoration(recyclerView.getContext(), layoutManager.getOrientation());
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(dividerItemDecoration);
        arrayAdapter = new NewAdapterContent(contentname,this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        getUsers();
        recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrolled(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
                total_item = layoutManager.getItemCount();
                last_visible_item = layoutManager.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
                if(!isLoading && total_item<=((last_visible_item+ITEM_LOAD_COUNT))){
                     getUsers();
                     isLoading = true;
                }
            }
        });

    }

    private void getUsers()
    {
        if (!isMaxData) {
            Query query;
            if (classname.equals("A")) {
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(last_nodes)) //wait content to aa n raehre
                    query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("ContentJokes")
                            .orderByChild("subcategory")
                            .equalTo(content)
                            .limitToFirst(ITEM_LOAD_COUNT);

                else
                    query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("ContentJokes")
                            .orderByChild("subcategory")
                            //.equalTo(content)
                            .startAt(last_nodes)
                            .limitToFirst(ITEM_LOAD_COUNT);
                //1 sec wait cll ari kisi ki


                query.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
                        if (!dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                            //hello ?
                            isLoading = false;
                            isMaxData = true;
                         //   progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            Toast.makeText(ContentActivity.this, "There is no jokes present under this category", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else {
                            String contentdisplay = dataSnapshot.child("content").getValue(String.class);
                            String key = dataSnapshot.child("content").getKey();
                            ContentModel contentModel = new ContentModel(contentdisplay, key);
                            contentname.add(0, contentModel);
                            arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            arrayAdapter.notifyItemInserted(0);
                            last_nodes = contentname.get(contentname.size() - 1).getId();
                            if (!last_nodes.equals(last_key)) {
                            } else
                                last_nodes = last_key;
                            isLoading = false;
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }


                });
            } else if(classname.equals("B")){
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(last_nodes)) //wait content to aa n raehre
                    query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("ContentShayari")
                            .orderByChild("subcategory")
                            .equalTo(content)
                            .limitToFirst(ITEM_LOAD_COUNT);

                else
                    query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("ContentShayari")
                            .orderByChild("subcategory")
                            .equalTo(content)
                            .startAt(last_nodes)
                            .limitToFirst(ITEM_LOAD_COUNT);


                query.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
                        if (!dataSnapshot.exists()) {

                            isLoading = false;
                            isMaxData = true;
                        //    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            Toast.makeText(ContentActivity.this, "There is no jokes present under this category", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else {
                            String contentdisplay = dataSnapshot.child("content").getValue(String.class);
                            String key = dataSnapshot.child("content").getKey();
                            ContentModel contentModel = new ContentModel(contentdisplay, key);
                            contentname.add(0, contentModel);
                            arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                          //  progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            arrayAdapter.notifyItemInserted(0);
                            last_nodes = contentname.get(contentname.size() - 1).getId();
                            if (!last_nodes.equals(last_key)) {
                            } else
                                last_nodes = last_key;
                            isLoading = false;
                        }

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }


                });
            }
        }
    }

    private void getLastKeyFromFirebase() {
        Query getLastKey;
        if (classname.equals("A")) {
            getLastKey = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
                    .child("ContentJokes")
                    .orderByChild("subcategory").equalTo(content)
                    .limitToLast(1);


            getLastKey.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    for (DataSnapshot lastKey : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        last_key = lastKey.getKey();
                        Toast.makeText(ContentActivity.this, String.valueOf(last_key), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    Toast.makeText(ContentActivity.this, "cannot get last key", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        } else if (classname.equals("B")) {
            getLastKey = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
                    .child("ContentShayari")
                    .orderByChild("subcategory").equalTo(content)
                    .limitToLast(1);


            getLastKey.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    for (DataSnapshot lastKey : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        last_key = lastKey.getKey();
                        Toast.makeText(ContentActivity.this, String.valueOf(last_key), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    Toast.makeText(ContentActivity.this, "cannot get last key", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }
    }

RecyclerAdapter Code:

    public class NewAdapterContent extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NewAdapterContent.ViewHolder> {
    ArrayList<ContentModel>contentModels;
    Context context;

    public NewAdapterContent(ArrayList<ContentModel>contentModels, Context context) {
        this.contentModels = contentModels;
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void addAll(ArrayList<ContentModel>contentModels){
        int initSize = contentModels.size();
        contentModels.addAll(contentModels);
        notifyItemRangeChanged(initSize, contentModels.size());
    }
    public String getLastItemId(){
         return contentModels.get(contentModels.size()-1).getId();
    }
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public NewAdapterContent.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.content, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull NewAdapterContent.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.textView.setText(contentModels.get(position).getContent());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return contentModels.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView textView;
        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            textView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.contentText);
        }
    }
}
```

Anytime of help would be appreciated. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Try it which is very easy to use that was worked for me by using the custom `RecyclerView.OnScrollListener` named [EndlessRecyclerViewScrollListener](https://gist.github.com/nesquena/8a976dd3d6f866518db2cfe7f9cb0db7#file-endlessrecyclerviewscrolllistener-java)   -

```
EndlessRecyclerViewScrollListener scrollListener = new 
             EndlessRecyclerViewScrollListener(layoutManager) {

        @Override
        public void onLoadMore(int page, int totalItemsCount, RecyclerView view) {
           if(!isLoading){
                 getUsers();
                 isLoading = true;
            }
        }
    };

    recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(scrollListener);
```

Comment: Did you test it by setting a log cat or debug breakpoint in "onLoadMore()"?

Comment: yes i have checked with debugger...debugger is going in that method but it is not adding data in list.

Comment: That means the problem is in the "getUser()" method not it is an issue from recyclerviewer. Just check that if it is getting any exception in firebase calling especially in "onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError)" . Add log or debugger everywhere you can see them.